# Can I call Gridview selected index function on pageload?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How can I call a gridview_SelectedIndexChanged event on page load?

Please guide me I'm using asp.net c#
Is this possible to use trigger method on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridview_SelectedIndexChanged(gridview, null);
}
```